# Missing dependency during rpm install

Tags: centos, package-management, software-installation, rpm

When I install CodeAnalsyt, i get a failed dependency on `libbfd-2.20.51` on Centos 6.3.
Binutils is installed on my system and the failed dependency does exists at 
`/usr/lib64/libbfd-2.20.51.0.2-5.34.el6.so`
Can someone please help with the install?

Comment: Are you installing a 32-bit or 64-bit program That library can only be used by a 64-bit program.

Answer (score 0):

Use yum, that figures dependencies out and handles the dowloading and installation for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing CodeAnalyst with `yum`:

```
yum localinstall <path to CodeAnalyst rpm>
```